# Remove some items in dropdownlist based on selected keywords

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in my page and the html part lists below:

```
<select  id="Permission_id" name="Permission_id"><option value="">Pls select</option>
 <option value="001f492b-fbb2-440c-b2ac-1fab5d97f5e3">super</option>
 <option value="559ede95-1dbb-45d5-ae41-2df6f460e87a">admin</option>
 <option value="80b330ee-37dc-42c4-8902-c30254112c11">user</option>
<select>
```

And in the same page, I have another dropdownlist , the html part lists below:

```
<select id="TopPranet_id" name="TopPranet_id"><option value="">Pls select</option>
 <option value="65c61442-e02f-4071-b746-2c7cbfcc859a">Settings--admin</option>
 <option value="66d21c35-66a2-40d8-a9db-675b337fa0bb">Control--admin</option>
 <option value="cd612bfc-9f61-4228-b986-90bda4be9d8d">Action--admin</option>
 <option value="2a137846-5ae0-4104-b0c9-be09a0e772d8">Settings--super</option>
 <option value="b75c43f3-cafb-41a2-a76b-c572fffd8a6a">Control--super</option>
 <option value="2c3f618c-373f-4559-967f-d8dcea1b6996">Action--super</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to do things like below:
When Permission_id's select item changes, then TopPranet_id's item will only contains the items that have Permission_id's selected text inside. that is, if I select admin in Permission_id control, then TopPranet_id control will only contains Settings--admin,Control--admin,Action--admin item, others are removed.

I know I can use Jquery to do this, but I am a newer to this, also, regex maybe also required for doing this. 
Need your help, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check here i have added one ex

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ekUTekA/1)

You html all seems ok

Now

in javascript

```
$('#Permission_id').change(function()
                             {

$('#TopPranet_id option').each(function()
                               {
  if(this.innerHTML.indexOf($('#Permission_id :selected').text())!=-1)
                                 {}
                                 else

                                 {
                                this.style.display='none';
                                 }

                               });

                             });
```

We have added **change function** which will detect the change event of the first dropdown and after this we will check that text with **second dropdown** which will show and hide the dropdowns